# Import an excel and insert into database

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

How to import an excel file and add the data into the database? I have the logic in the controller (I think) but I'm unsure how to send it from the vue to the controller? I'm basing this code on another project I was working on and tutorials but I don't know how to adapt it to my project.

This is the controller store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $users = $request->all();
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $dbUser = $this->getUser($user['CARNET']);
            Log::error($dbUser);
            $dbUser->name = $user['NOMBRE'];
            $dbUser->card = $user['CEDULA'];
            $dbUser->scard = $user['CARNET'];
            $dbUser->email = $user['CORREO'];
            $dbUser->password = $user['PASSWORD'];

            $this->isSet('TIPO-USUARIO', $user);
            $user_type_id = $this->getUserId($user['TIPO-USUARIO']);
            $dbUser->user_type_id = $user_type_id->id;

            $dbUser->save();

            foreach (explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user['CATEGORIA-USUARIO'])) as $c) {
                $category = $this->getCategory($c);
                $dbUser->userCategory()->save($category);
            }

            $dbUser->save();
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error importando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }
}
```

What I have in my vue

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="inputfile" id="fileUpload"/>
<label for="fileUpload">Select Excel</label>

<el-button
    style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 20px"
    type="primary"
    class="mt-1"
    :loading="loading"
    @click="sendData()">Import
</el-button>
```

```
sendData(data) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.error = {};
    this.$http.post(this.baseUrl, data, this.params)
        .then(
            () => {
                this.successAction();
                this.errorDis = false;

            },
            (res) => {
                this.showErrors(res);
                 this.errorDis = true;
            }
        );
},
successAction() {
    this.loading = false
},
showErrors(res) {
    const [message, errors] = parseError(res);
    this.error = {
        message,
        errors
    };
    this.loading = false;
    this.processing = false;
},
```

I'm not sure how to send the actual data to the controller to be able to save it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Laravel-Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) to read the file, create an object or array and store the data on the table that you want. In the view (blade, vue, jQuery, whatever) you just must send the file as POST though a route like this:

```
Route::post('/importExcel', 'YourController@importExcelmethod');
```

In the controller you could make something like this:

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    if($request->file('import_file')){
        $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path, function($reader) {
        })->get()->toArray();
        if(!empty($data) && (count($data)> 0)){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                DB::table('your_table')->insert(
                    [
                        "a_column" => $value[0],
                        "another_comun" => $value[1],
                        //etc
                    ]
                );
            }
```

More info here and examples here: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/

Actually there are some easier examples on how to store data to a Model from the xls like this:

```
public function import() 
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');

    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'All good!');
}
```

Comment: I installed that, but again not sure how to use it

Comment: Ok, you could say that. I will edit my answer then, wait